# why am I not able to do anything after this?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

when using mysql command line, I forgot to put a ' in the varchar input and this is the result. No matter how many times I try to enter some other things nothing is happening. Can anyone tell me why this happening? [image]

Comment: Maybe try hitting `Ctrl-C` ?

Comment: will this work: `'\c`

Answer (score 1):

The `mysql` command line program is waiting for you to complete an incomplete quoted string; it shows `>` continuation line prompts.

Either finish the string with a closing `'`, or better, use `<ctrl>-c` to abandon your input and try again.